# PHP Ajax works with get but not with post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send a some data via ajax post and on server perform some task and then return result back. here is an ex: i have done

```
  function sometask(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajaxPost/task/',
        data: {title: 'test', text: 'test2'},
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('failed');
        }
    });
  }
```

on server side

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
```

on html Do something

expected result was data sent via ajax returned as an array. but its returning empty array.

when changed type to 'GET' on ajax and on server side var_dump($_GET); the data is returned.

So why does it work with get and not with post, where i have gone wrong?

Comment: try serializing your data 


[Simmilar ask][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: Don't listen to @kiamnemr, there's nothing wrong with your code. I would recommend using a non-directory resource, ie instead of `/ajaxPost/task/`, try `/ajaxPost/task/index.php` (or whatever your script name actually is)

Comment: updated my question my scenario is different i am not submitting form.

Comment: thank Phil but i am using a routing protocol to reach so the file path is totally different from url i am sending data to.

Comment: its an custom MVC framework. so the actual code sits in /app/controllers/ajaxPostController.php

Comment: @AbhishekSalian How does the *routing protocol* work? Any chance it turns POST requests into GET? Try adding both `$_GET` and `$_POST` `var_dump()` statements into your PHP code.

Comment: So you actually get a return of something like `Array()` ?

Comment: yup when with post the output is array(0) {} and with get the output is array(2) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["text"]=>
  string(5) "test2"
}

Comment: @AbhishekSalian I just tried this on my dev server and it worked as expected, leading me to believe that somewhere else (in your php) there is something possibly stripping `POST` or an error occuring. Turn on error reporting (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and let me know if anything pops up.

Comment: @Darren error reporting is enable, there is noting which strips post, i even tried dumping post on index at the very first line even before routing is called and same result. so ajax is not sending post data at all, thats what i think. and i have regular php form in same page with post method that works but not the ajax post.

Comment: @AbhishekSalian Check the *Network* tab in your browser's developer console. You should see the AJAX POST request and subsequent response(s)

Comment: @AbhishekSalian It does work as I've tried your example **exactly the same way**, could you try something like `http://www.yoursite.com/AjaxPost/task`? Also check with Phil's comment above

Comment: @phil and Darren thanks guys, yes there is some sort of issue going on i am getting 2 event on network tab - task/ POST 301 and second task GET 200 not sure whats going on

Comment: Somewhere in your php or server settings you are redirecting POST request to GET

Comment: @AbhishekSalian Yup, see my [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026663/php-ajax-works-with-get-but-not-with-post?noredirect=1#comment38921127_25026663). I'd say you need to check your *routing protocol*. Looks like it's performing a [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: ok i tried again with full url and same result. so i accessed the page directly http://locahost:8080/ajaxPost/task it works.

Comment: thanks a lot guys fixed it, i changed url to /ajaxPost/task and it worked so the '/' at the end caused all this issues. Still I have no idea how get worked with '/' at the end.

Comment: @AbhishekSalian Something in your code or configuration was redirecting the request using a PRG pattern. Also note that I did suggest in my first comment that you use a *non-directory resource*

Comment: @phil thanks, maybe i didnt get what you said earlier. i was thinking that you wanted me to point ajax url to the file :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in google chrome  F12  networktab..

see how data is send, and compare with a normal post request (without jquery ajax)

you probably get the answer

Comment: Whilst this is a good approach to debugging the problem, this *answer* does not provide (or attempt to provide) a solution

Answer (score -1):

I think it just depends on how complex of a task you are trying to run. The $.ajax function is for tasks that require better error reporting as well as other callbacks that you can access to. I usually run just a $.post function to complete most data exchanges. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: i tried $.post same result. what error reporting are you talking about. i have enabled error reporting in php and even logging errors, havent seen any errors when trying ajax submit.